# Issue of sendNotification with REST api to KAA

Tags: rest, api, kaa

According to KAA documents, send Notification to KAA with below command,

```
curl -v -S -u devuser:devuser123 -F'notification={"applicationId":"3","schemaId":"20","topicId:"1","type":"USER"};type=application/json' -F file=@/home/richard/notification.json "http://192.168.30.27:8080/kaaAdmin/rest/api/sendNotification"
```

I'm sure that the IP address of KAA server and notification settings are right. But get below errors,

> HTTP/1.1 100 Continue HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

Any guys meet the same issue and could you please give some clue?

Comment: Can you try adding a space between `-F` and `notification=` like `curl -v -S -u devuser:devuser123 -F 'notification=`

Comment: Thanks. Try the modification, but get same error.

Comment: Hi, Any guys know where parse REST API in kaa server source tree?

Answer (score 1):

**Response Messages: 400    The specified notification is not valid**

I think you need to check your message's style for notification.json.

My message style is **{ "Message": "Hello world!"}** and .avsc file is :

```
{
  "type" : "record",
  "name" : "Message",
  "namespace" : "hello.world.com",
  "fields" : [ {
    "name" : "Message",
    "type" : {
      "type" : "string",
      "avro.java.string" : "String"
    },
    "displayName" : "",
    "displayPrompt" : ""
  } ],
  "version" : 1,
  "dependencies" : [ ],
  "displayName" : "Message",
  "description" : ""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe in your notification body schemas any field is optional. you need change your json file. for example:

{"notifId" : "16243",
"notifInfo": {"string":"this is info"},
"notifType" : 90,
"notifPayload" : "this is payload"
}

notifInfo is optional